# Error when using yarn: `Cannot find module 'worker_threads'`

Tags: yarnpkg

I get an error when using yarn 3.x

```
Error: Cannot find module 'worker_threads'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at C:\It\xxxxx\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.cjs:423:2587
```

Answer (score 1):

Error was solved by upgrading node to lts

```
nvm install lts
nvm use lts
```